# Finding rows with same values in two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 columns in Postgres database having table mytable and i want records having only duplicate values in 2nd and 3rd column.

```
SQL> select * from mytable ;

column1      column2       column3

  A            1            50----required output ie. 50 is duplicate in line B column 2
  B            50           3 ----required output ie. 50 is duplicate in line A column 3
  C            2            10----values are duplicate in others lines
  D            30           70----required output ie. 30 is duplicate in line E column 3
  E            8            30----required output ie. 30 is duplicate in line D column 2
  F            40           25----values are not duplicate in others lines
```

I want the following output with count(*):

```
 column1      column2       column3

  A            1            50
  B            50           3
  D            30           70
  E            8            30
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a self join to handle this:

```
select distinct m.*
from mytable m
inner join mytable m2
    on (
        m.column2 in (m2.column2, m2.column3)
        or m.column3 in (m2.column2, m2.column3)
       )
    and m.column1 <> m2.column1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (select 1
              from mytable t2
              where t.col2 in (t2.col2, t2.col3) or
                    t.col3 in (t2.col2, t2.col3)
             );
```